# Paypal checkout and mass payment integration with cakephp

Tags: cakephp, paypal, payment-processing

I'm dealing with a problem when starting with a project evolving cakephp and paypal.
I never used paypal in my life and I have a lot of questions about it. I want to know if any of you have ever seen a really starter tutorial to paypal development and a good cakephp plugin to perform this.

The project consists of a payment system by credit card that generates a commission at the end of the process for sellers. This commission will be paid through paypal mass payment.

I'm interested in found out a good cakephp open code that allows me to do all of that.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like [this tutorial](http://www.webtechnick.com/blogs/view/218/CakePHP_Paypal_IPN_Plugin) is exactly for you. Basically in to play with Paypal you have to create sandbox account (it's explained in the post) and you can play with fake CC and data